# Rationale behind behavior of `git checkout HEAD`

Tags: git, git-checkout

When doing `git checkout HEAD` i checkout the commit my `HEAD` points to. I use it to trigger some hooks after doing a `git reset --hard origin/master` for example.

What's the rationale behind not ending up on a detached `HEAD` after doing it though? In the case above, I am still on whatever branch i had checked out before the reset. I don't have a problem with this, but to me the semantics don't feel aligned with other operations. I would expect to end up on the very same commit, but with a detached `HEAD` (this could also be useful, perhaps it's possible somehow).

Comment: `HEAD` contains what is currently checked out. You can see it by doing `cat .git/HEAD`. So if you are on branch, it contains this branch (`ref: refs/heads/master`). So, you checked out this branch and don't end in a detached head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git checkout --detach HEAD
```

or simply

```
git checkout --detach
```

to checkout the `HEAD` commit itself in a detached `HEAD` state.

That being said, `checkout` can indeed be a somewhat confusing command at times (which prompted git's developers to recently introduce [`restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) and [`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)).

Keep in mind that in your theoretical case, `HEAD` is not pointing directly at a commit but at a branch.

```
A---B---C <<< master <<< HEAD
```

When you checkout `HEAD`, you re-checkout that branch rather than its tip commit directly (unless you explicitly specify otherwise).